# Why is <button> "clicked" on form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, preventdefault

Pressing <kbd>return</kbd> on the `<input>` of the form in the code below seems to trigger two events:

- `submit` event,
- `click` event for the first `<button>` in the form.

`preventDefault` seems to cancel the `submit` event, but the `click` event is not stopped because it is triggered *before* the `submit` event. I could replace `<button>` with an `<input type="button">`, but why is the `<button>` clicked at all? How can I prevent it?

Here is the form http://jsfiddle.net/MNXUS/:

```
<form>
  <button></button>
  <input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just what browsers do.  If you don't want the button to submit the form, you can make it a "button" button instead of a "submit" button:

```
<button type=button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Wow "button" is one of those words that looks like it's misspelled if you look at it for too long.

Comment: Also I saw a presentation at SXSW a couple years ago about "The History Of The Button". It was fascinating.